# angular-ui bootstrap datepicker options use function instead of json

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

Given my code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="dd-MM-yyyy" ng-model="addNoPayRows[$index].date" is-open="addNoPayPopup[$index].opened"  ng-required="true" close-text="Close" datepicker-options="datepickerOptions($index)"/>
```

and js

```
$scope.datepickerOptions = function(index) {
            if(index == 0) {
                return {showWeeks:false, minDate:$scope.today};
            } else {
                return {showWeeks:false, minDate: $scope.addNoPayRows[index-1].date};
            }
        }
```

there might be multiple datepicker on the page. my goal is, if it is the first date picker, then the `minDate` is set as today, otherwise the `minDate` should be set as no early than the previous selected date

I try to do it in a function way, but it always reports

```
10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [[{"msg":"fn: function (c,e,f,g){f=d&&g?g[0]:a(c,e,f,g);return b(f,c,e)}","newVal":{"showWeeks":false,"minDate":"2016-08-01T08:16:05.956Z"},"oldVal":{"showWeeks":false,"minDate":"2016-08-01T08:16:05.956Z"}},{"msg":"fn: function (c,e,f,g){f=d&&g?g[0]:a(c,e,f,g);return b(f,c,e)}","newVal":{"showWeeks":false,"minDate":null},"oldVal":{"showWeeks":false,"minDate":null}}],[{"msg":"fn: function (c,e,f,g){f=d&&g?g[0]:a(c,e,f,g);return b(f,c,e)}","newVal":{"showWeeks":false,"minDate":"2016-08-01T08:16:05.956Z"},"oldVal":{"showWeeks":false,"minDate":"2016-08-01T08:16:05.956Z"}},{"msg":"fn: function (c,e,f,g){f=d&&g?g[0]:a(c,e,f,g);return b(f,c,e)}","newVal":{"showWeeks":false,"minDate":null},"oldVal":{"showWeeks":false,"minDate":null}}],[{"msg":"fn: function (c,e,f,g){f=d&&g?g[0]:a(c,e,f,g);return b(f,c,e)}","newVal":{"showWeeks":false,"minDate":"2016-08-01T08:16:05.956Z"},"oldVal":{"showWeeks":false,"minDate":"2016-08-01T08:16:05.956Z"}},{"msg":"fn: function (c,e,f,g){f=d&&g?g[0]:a(c,e,f,g);return b(f,c,e)}","newVal":{"showWeeks":false,"minDate":null},"oldVal":{"showWeeks":false,"minDate":null}}],[{"msg":"fn: function (c,e,f,g){f=d&&g?g[0]:a(c,e,f,g);return b(f,c,e)}","newVal":{"showWeeks":false,"minDate":"2016-08-01T08:16:05.956Z"},"oldVal":{"showWeeks":false,"minDate":"2016-08-01T08:16:05.956Z"}},{"msg":"fn: function (c,e,f,g){f=d&&g?g[0]:a(c,e,f,g);return b(f,c,e)}","newVal":{"showWeeks":false,"minDate":null},"oldVal":{"showWeeks":false,"minDate":null}}],[{"msg":"fn: function (c,e,f,g){f=d&&g?g[0]:a(c,e,f,g);return b(f,c,e)}","newVal":{"showWeeks":false,"minDate":"2016-08-01T08:16:05.956Z"},"oldVal":{"showWeeks":false,"minDate":"2016-08-01T08:16:05.956Z"}},{"msg":"fn: function (c,e,f,g){f=d&&g?g[0]:a(c,e,f,g);return b(f,c,e)}","newVal":{"showWeeks":false,"minDate":null},"oldVal":{"showWeeks":false,"minDate":null}}]]
```

any idea how to implement this? thanks

---

Edit:

```
$scope.today = new Date();
```

even if the function is written as

```
$scope.datepickerOptions = function(index) {           
    return {showWeeks:false, minDate:$scope.today};
}
```

so I suspect it cannot be done by function

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.today` should be a Date Object/Moment Object(assuming you have it), then for the second date picker instead of `$scope.addNoPayRows[index-1].date` you can have `$scope.today` and then you can add a watcher over the `ng-model` of the first date-picker as:

Have an array of minDate where each element is a minDate for eachDate Picker, which can be initilised as:

```
$scope.minDates = [$scope.today, $scope.today];
$scope.datepickerOptions = function(index) {
   return {showWeeks:false, minDate:$scope.minDates[index]};   
};

// Watcher
$scope.$watch(function(){return $scope.addNoPayRows[0].date;}, 
   function(){
     $scope.minDates[1] = $scope.addNoPayRows[0].date;
});
```

Comment: $scope.datepickerOptions = function(index) {
   return {showWeeks:false, minDate:$scope.today};   
}; even this one is not working. have the same problem as above